# Figuring out the integral of a function that is defined differently in a single point than the rest of the domaine

Tags: integration

This is my first post and English is not primary language, so I'm sorry if I mess it up.
So my question is if i have a function that is, for example, defined like this:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x-4 & x\in[-3, 5]\setminus \{2\}\\
2 & x\in\{2\}
\end{cases}
$$
Okay, so if this is defined like this, how does the definition in x=2 affect the definite integral in bounds [-3, 5]?
Will we just use the first expression throughout the whole integral, or do we need do break it down in some way to acommodate for that one point?
Also, what would happen if, for example, the first part of the domaine was written as [-3, 5), how would the excluding bracket affect the integral?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The value of a function at a single point (or on a set of points of measure zero) does not affect the value of its integral.

Comment: Have you heard of the "measure" ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the improper integral in a descontinuity
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{x\rightarrow c^-}\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx+\lim_{x\rightarrow c^+}\int_{c}^{b}f(x)dx $$

Comment: you can try this, but i don´t know if its 100% right, as I can't make a comment due to my reputation, I posted it as an answer, sorry.